# Click table row to show more information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use jQuery to achieve the following.

[image]

When a table row is clicked, the info div within the table row is displayed, and if another table row is clicked, any other info element that is currently displayed will be hidden, and the new info div will be displayed according to the table row that has been clicked.

This problem is, the code isn't working correctly. I've played around with several alternatives but I can't seem to achieve the desired results.

This is going to be part of a contacts page, the table will show a list of contacts, and when a contact is clicked, you can see more data about that specific contact.

PLEASE NOTE: Using a table is not important, it can be a ul, ol, div.. anything.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("tr").click(function() {
      if ($(this).find("> .info").css('display') == 'none') {
        $(this).find("> .info").show();
      } else {
        $(this).find("> .info").hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
    <td>joebloggs@email.com</td>
    <div class="info">555.555.555</div>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sam Doe</td>
    <td>samdoe@email.com</td>
    <div class="info">556.556.556</div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: whats exactly your question/or where you are stuck? I could'nt understand your problem exactly

Comment: Your html code is not value, please take your time and fix it, you have 1 tr and 2 /tr

Comment: You have a missing `<tr>` tag just before the `<td>` of Sam Doe

Answer (score 1):

After adding the missing `<tr>` to your table, try use `.is(":visible")` to check if the element is vision

You also dont need to use `>` in `.find("> .info")`

Example below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("tr").click(function() {
      if (!$(this).find(".info").is(":visible")) {
        $(this).find(".info").show();
      } else {
        $(this).find(".info").hide();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
    <td>joebloggs@email.com</td>
    <td>
      <div class="info">555.555.555</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sam Doe</td>
    <td>samdoe@email.com</td>
    <td>
      <div class="info">556.556.556</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you miss `<tr>` in your code.

- `div` element will not use directly as a child of `tr`
- Have to add `div` in `td`

**EDIT**

- Now here you can use `addClass` for `tr` `child div` element and `removeClass` `tr` siblings `child div`

Here is working snippet you can check this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("tr").click(function() {
          $(this).find("div[class*='info']").addClass('show');
          $(this).siblings().find("div[class*='info']").removeClass('show');
      });
});
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
    <td>joebloggs@email.com</td>
    <td><div class="info">555.555.555</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sam Doe</td>
    <td>samdoe@email.com</td>
    <td><div class="info">556.556.556</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'm trying to achieve, but how how do you then modify the js so that, if another info is already being displayed, it it will be hidden when a different tr is clicked? If that makes sense... :\

Comment: @JakeDuncan you can check my answer if it is helpful to you

Comment: @JakeDuncan i just update the code.. check it. it might helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to achieve your purpose:-

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('tr').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.more-info').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: solid 1px #000;
}

.more-info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>thead</th>
      <th>thead</th>
      <th>thead</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
      <td>column</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="more-info">
      <td colspan="3">More Info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not use div directly, but you can achive same thing using this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(function() {
      $("tr").click(function() {
      $('tr.visible').removeClass('visible').addClass('info'); $(this).next('tr').addClass('visible').removeClass('info');          
      });
  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
    <td>joebloggs@email.com</td>
    
  </tr>
  <tr class="info"><td colspan="2"><div>555.555.555</div></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sam Doe</td>
    <td>samdoe@email.com</td>
       <div class="info">556.556.556</div>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info"><td colspan="2"><div>556.556.556</div></td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's some problems with your code:

1. First of all you can not use div as direct child of tr. You need to wrap it with td.
2. No need to run jquery initialization twice: 
   `$(document).ready(function() {
   $(function() {`

Here is example how you can do it:
HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
    <td>joebloggs@email.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td collspan="2"><div>555.555.555</div></td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
    <td>Sam Doe</td>
    <td>samdoe@email.com</td>    
    </tr>
    <tr class="info">
      <td colspan="2">
          <div>556.556.556</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('tr').not('.info').on('click', function() {
        $('.info').hide();
      $(this).next('.info').show();
    });      
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("tr").on("click", function(){
  if ($(this).find(".info").css('display') == 'none') 
   {
       $(this).find(".info").show();
   } else 
   {
       $(this).find(".info").hide();
   }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.info {
  display: none;
}
</style>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Joe Bloggs</td>
    <td>joebloggs@email.com
       <div class="info">555.555.555</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Sam Doe</td>
    <td>samdoe@email.com
      <div class="info">556.556.556</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```